# How to use foreach with snow for multicore in Windows XP?

Tags: r, statistics, parallel-processing

Could you please give an example on how that might be done using the doSNOW ?

(I asked the same question [here](http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2009/08/parallel-programming-with-foreach-and-snow.html), but only got a partial reply)
Tal

Answer (score 3):

I fear that you are getting a few things muddled up and confused, as you did in your recent post on the r-help list:

1. Think about it from the bottom up.
2. You need a mechanism for parallel computing, whether or not it involves several machines.
3. The [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) package does that for you, which is one of the reasons we highlighted it in the [JSS survey paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01)
4. You can start with snow, which in the simplest case works a) on Windows and b) does not require MPI or PVM -- just use sockets
5. Once you have that figured out, move 'up' to higher levels of abstraction of using snow with the [doSNOW](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doSNOW) backend to support [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach).
6. The [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/package=multicore) package does not (yet?) work on Windows and is of no (current?) use to you, so ignore it at least for now. Likewise for its [doMC](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doMC) backend.

Working examples exist for each step along the way. I always fall back to verifying by test cases what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Is this still correct (answer is from Sep 09), that multicore does not work on Windows. Does this mean that multicore functionality of parrallel package in R 2.14.0 also does not work on Windows?

Comment: Yes, and no, and details are in the vignette and other documentation for the parallels package.